# words that differ by one letter

Tags: java

I am trying to read words from a file(which I Already did), and then write those words that " differ by one letter " into a new output file(PrintWriter class). I do not know how to compare words that differ by one letter. I am not that familiar with ArrayList. Thanks for the help in advance. 
Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> words2=new ArrayList<>();
// I created words2 so i could compare it to words
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {  
 // words includes the words read from file 
        System.out.print(words.get(i)+" ");
          for(int j=0; j<words.size();j++){
             words2=words;
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a Java book for beginners.

Comment: I think this question may be simply too broad for Stack Overflow. But you would probably find this blog post very relevant: [Find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/).

Comment: Oracle Docs on the [List Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) 
 and [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) may be helpful

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63531183/839733); it's in Python, but solves the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define all the cases where words differ in one character. For instance, are the following two considered as valid cases? are there any other?

```
might vs. mighty
male vs. mall
```

If there's only one case which you consider valid, you can implement an algorithm which will compare each word against all the others, compare letter by letter and count the ones which are not equals, filtering in only pairs of words which have a "diff-count" of exactly 1.

Otherwise, there's a known algorithm called [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which you can either implement or find a library that implements it and use it.