# Find all the words in the list that differ by a single letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-itertools

For any given word `w` in a list `words`, I want to find all the other words in the list that can become `w` by changing a single letter in them. All words are of equal length, and only substitution is allowed. Call this function `parent(w)`.

For example, given `words = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]`, `parent("cog")` would be `["dog", "log"]`. `parent("lot")` would be `["dot", "hot", "log"]` etc.

To do this, I first build a reverse index where the keys `(str, int)` map to the words that have character `str` at index `int`. Then, finding the parents of a word becomes the task of intersecting all the words that have the same letters as the word in the same positions, except for one.

The code is as follows, which produces an empty set. Why is it not working?

```
from typing import Iterator, Dict, Tuple, Set
import itertools

graph: Dict[Tuple[str, int], Set[int]] = dict()

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    for j, ch in enumerate(word):
        if (ch, j) not in graph:
            graph[(ch, j)] = set()

        graph[(ch, j)].add(i)

def parents(word: str) -> Iterator[int]:
    n: int = len(word)
    s: Set[int] = set()
    for part in itertools.combinations(range(n), n - 1):
        keys = map(lambda x: (word[x], x), part)
        existing_keys = filter(lambda k: k in graph, keys)
        for y in itertools.chain(map(lambda k: graph[k], existing_keys)):
            s = s.intersection(set(y)) if s else set(y)

    return filter(lambda i: words[i] != word, s)

print(list(parents("cog"))) # empty!!!
```

Comment: What is that `itertools.chain` supposed to be doing? Right now it's not doing anything.

Comment: Can you use `difflib`? See `get_close_matches`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches

Comment: `[w for w in words if len(set(word) - set(w)) == 1]`.

Comment: @ekhumoro that doesn't take into account the order of letters

Comment: @superbrain the `words` list is given in the question, the rest works with that one declaration

Comment: @ggorlen `difflib` seems to be too generic for my purpose; it doesn't have an option to specify how many letters can be changed, and doesn't take advantage of the fact that the words are of equal length.

Comment: @ekhumoro `words = ["log"]; word = "olx"; print([w for w in words if len(set(word) - set(w)) == 1])`

Comment: @JakubDąbek `[w for w in words if len(set(enumerate(word)) - set(enumerate(w))) == 1]`?

Comment: @ekhumoro For words of equal length, that looks like a correct solution :D This is basically a simplified version of OP's code without the intermediate structure. Depending on lookup frequency and the data it might be faster overall.

Comment: @JakubDąbek Okay! Although I must admit my original comment was somewhat tongue in cheek. The real point of the question was about getting the OP's chosen solution to work properly (which it seems they have now done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution. A different approach.

Complexity: `O(N * 26) => O(N)` - where N is the number of characters in each word.

```
def main(words, word):
    words = set(words)
    res = []
    for i, _ in enumerate(word):
        for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            w = word[:i] + c + word[i+1:]
            if w != word and w in words:
                res.append(w)
    return res


print(main(["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"], "cog"))
# ['dog', 'log']
```

---

Instead of iterating over all the alphabets, you can also choose to only iterate on the alphabets that are occurring in the list using:

```
{letter for w in words for letter in w}
```

Comment: Technically, the DS I created is not a trie, because it doesn't have a root.

Comment: Your code is tad simpler, but you made an assumption that only lower case alphabets are used. The question didn't say so. If this was an interview question (it actually is part of an interview question), you're gonna get dinged. Also note that you do multiple substring operations, whereas in my code, I take advantage of the fact that the words are of equal length, so the number of combinations are constant.

Comment: There’s also a way to only work on the letters that are in the list. But yes, for the first solution, the assumption is true.

Comment: Turns out, my code doesn't work for `words = ["a", "b", "c"]` and `word = "a".` I'll accept your answer as correct. Note that you can replace `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` with `string.ascii_lowercase`;

Comment: `O(N * K)`, what's `K`? `N` I'm guessing is the word length.

Comment: This was a derived solution from one of the other problems. There is no K. My bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is almost there. The problem is that you're intersecting *everything* you find. But instead you should append your results for each combination. Move `s: Set[int] = set()` inside your first for loop, and append your results after the second for loop and it'll work. Something like this:

```
def parents(word: str) -> Set[int]:
    ret: Set[int] = set()
    for part in itertools.combinations(range(n), n - 1):
        keys = map(lambda x: (word[x], x), part)
        existing_keys = filter(lambda k: k in graph, keys)
        s: Set[int] = set()
        for y in map(lambda k: graph[k], existing_keys):
            s = s.intersection(set(y)) if s else set(y)

        ret.update(filter(lambda i: words[i] != word, s))

    return ret
```

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The check for keys that exist in the graph is superfluous. Try `parents("xxg")`, which bypasses the later checks because of that. Using `(graph.get(k, set()) for k in keys)` does what you want, substituting an empty set when there had been no words with that letter in that position.

Comment: Doesn't work for `words = ["a", "b", "c"]` and `word = "a"`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63531183/839733) does.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Might as well just do `if len(word) <= 1: return set(range(len(words)))` then, as it is a special case within the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The Levenshtein distance algorithm will achive what you are looking for.

```
from Levenshtein import distance  # pip install python-Levenshtein

words = ["hot", "dot", "dog", "lot", "log", "cog"]
parent = 'cog'
# find all words matching with one substitution
edits = [w for w in words if distance(parent, w) == 1]
print(edits)
```

Output:

```
['dog', 'log']
```

If you don't want to install any libraries, there are good [online resources](https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/) with Python implementations of the algorithm.

Comment: I'm aware of Levenshtein algorithm, although I didn't know a Python module exists for that. I'd prefer not installing additional dependencies though. The algorithm in my question should work as shown, the question is really, why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I would check every letter of the parent word w against each of the words from the list using the Python in function.

For example for `parent("cog")` against the list of words:

```
["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]
```

yields:

```py
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

Numbers 2 show the correct words: dog and log.